# html/liquid <label> not working in a form, can't figure out why

Tags: html, forms, label, liquid

I'm completely new to liquid and almost completely new to HTML so I expect this to be an easy one.
I have a shopify website I'm editing for a friend; his delivery capability is limited so he wants to find out roughly where customers are before their account is fully registered.
So, as per some online tutorials (which I admit looked slightly different) I added an extra field into the `customers/register.liquid` template asking for location.

```
<div id = "location" class="clearfix large form"
    <label for="custloc_check" class="login">Delivery</label>
    <input
        type="text"
        id="custloc_check"
        name="customer[note][Location]"
        placeholder="Please indicate rough delivery location"
        />
</div>
```

I can't actually *see* anything wrong with it, but the line beginning `<label` is all red (where elsewhere on the form the `label` lines are in varying colours) so that would indicate that's where the problem is? And of course there's no evidence whatsoever of it in the form on the website.

Expect it's a really basic error, but any help much appreciated, thank you!!

Comment: Typo. You forgot the `>` for the div start tag on the previous line.

Comment: @Pain — Don't edit questions to remove the problem they are asking about!

Comment: @Quentin Thanks, and yes it's edited, but the field still isn't showing in the form? (as in after saving the code and then hitting preview). Are there any other obvious errors or am I just looking at the wrong bit of code now?

Comment: If it helps, I took the cue from [this tutorial](https://shopify.dev/tutorials/customize-theme-get-more-information-with-customer-registration-form)

Comment: https://jsbin.com/fayitoxeku/1/edit?html,output — It shows up fine when I test it.

Comment: @Quentin you're right it does - I had overlooked the fact that there's a 'register' section on the 'login' page, as well as a separate 'register' page - I'd inserted the code into one and was looking at the other!! All good now though ... many thanks for your help!!